# Python Pillow / PIL ライブラリを Mavericks (10.9.5) にインストールできない

Tags: python, macos, pil, pillow

OS Marvericks で PIL を使うを方法について質問させていただきます。

現在、Mac (OS 10.9.5 Mavericks) で Python を使用しており、Xcode(6.1), X11(2.7.7), The freetype(2.5.3_1.), Python(2.7.6.), はすでにインストール済です。

画像処理をするために、PIL (もしくは Pillow ) をインストールしようとしているのですが、うまくいきません。類似したトラブルが本家 Stack Overflow でも報告されており、参考にしましたが、やはりインストールできずにおります。

具体的な現状は下記の通りです。同様のエラーを修正できた方、または Python に詳しい方がおりましたら、ご教示いただければ幸いです (当方、Python を最近勉強し始めました)。

```
_imagingft.c:73:10: fatal error: 'freetype/fterrors.h' file not found
**#include freetype/fterrors.h
 ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

上記インストールエラーが出たため、下記を入力

```
ln -s /usr/local/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

するとターミナル上で下記が表示されたので、

```
ln: /usr/local/include/freetype: File exists
```

さらに下記を入力しました

```
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

しかし、改善されず、インストールできずにおります。

上記の各対応は本家 Stack Overflow を参考にしたものです (本家では残念ながら、この質問への回答がありません)。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip 1.5以上のバージョンで `pip install pillow` でビルド無しでインストールできます。

手元は Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 ですが、10.9.5でも同じだと思います。

```
MacBook-Pro:tmp $ virtualenv -p python2.7 v
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in v/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

MacBook-Pro:tmp $ cd v

MacBook-Pro:v $ source bin/activate

(v)MacBook-Pro:v $ pip install -U pip
Downloading/unpacking pip from https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-6.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=0472d9dc76a0df6cc6ab545e40aef832
Downloading pip-6.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB): 1.3MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: pip
Found existing installation: pip 1.5.6
Uninstalling pip:
Successfully uninstalled pip
Successfully installed pip
Cleaning up...

(v)MacBook-Pro:v $ pip --version
pip 6.0.6 from /private/tmp/v/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

(v)MacBook-Pro:v $ pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
Downloading Pillow-2.7.0-cp27-none-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.8MB)
100% |################################| 2.8MB 2.5MB/s
Installing collected packages: Pillow

Successfully installed Pillow-2.7.0

(v)MacBook-Pro:v $ pip freeze
Pillow==2.7.0
```

ビルドしたい、となると色々大変だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ビルドする方法はあるのでしょうか (インストールはできました)。
画像処理の際、他ライブラリも使用しているのですが、プログラムを実行すると、下記エラーがでます。
ImportError: '関数名' can not be initialized.
The Python package 'Python Imaging Library (PIL)' is not installed.
Exception AttributeError: "'関数名' object has no attribute '_compression_filename'" in <bound method 関数名.__del__ of <関数名 object at 0x2b55b0>> ignored

Comment: 横から失礼します。
他のpipでインストールしたパッケージのimportはできるのでしょうか？
例えば、pillowと同じ手順で`pip install arrow`として`arrow`をインストールし、`python`コマンドでインタープリタ（`>>> `というマークが出るはずです）を起動し、`from arrow import Arrow`はエラーなく実行できますでしょうか？また、同様にインタープリタからPILをimportしてもエラーになりますか？

Comment: 質問の趣旨が変わってきてるようなので別の質問で以下を書くと良いと思います。1. インストールの手順。2. 実行手順。3. 発生したトレースバックの全文

Comment: @Miyako 他のパッケージでは、importできるものとそうでないものがあります。例として上げているarrowですが、インストールはできますがimportはできません。しかし、numpyはimportできました。importできない際には、Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from arrow import Arrow
ImportError: No module named arrow　というエラーがでます (他のimportできないライブラリも同様のエラーです)。
Pillowもこのエラーが出て、importできずにおります。

Comment: @Rikka shimizukawaさんもおっしゃっているように、別質問をたてて詳しく状況を説明した方がいいと思います。

Comment: @Miyako SHIMIZUSAWA  ご指摘ありがとうございます。[http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5875/python-pillow-pil%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92mavericks-10-9-5-%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84]で質問させていただきました。