# Python Pillow/PILライブラリをMavericks (10.9.5) で使えない

Tags: python, macos, pil, pillow

OS Marvericks で PillowもしくはPIL を使うを方法について質問させていただきます。

現在、Mac (OS 10.9.5 Mavericks) で Python を使用しており、Xcode(6.1), X11(2.7.7), The freetype(2.5.3_1.), Python(2.7.6.), はすでにインストール済です。

画像処理をするために、Pillow (2.6.1) をインストールしました ([Python Pillow / PIL ライブラリを Mavericks (10.9.5) にインストールできない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5067/python-pillow-pil-%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92-mavericks-10-9-5-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84))。

ところが実際に使用しようとするとエラーが出て、使用できません。類似したトラブルが本家 Stack Overflow でも報告されており、参考にしましたが、使えずにおります。

詳しい現状は下記の通りです。同様のエラーを修正できた方、または Python に詳しい方がおりましたら、ご教示いただければ幸いです (当方、Python を最近勉強し始めました)。

```
pip install pillow
```

で、pillow はインストールされました。
インストール済は下記の通りです。

```
$pip freeze
Pillow==2.6.1
PyOpenGL==3.1.0
arrow==0.5.0
nose==1.3.3
numpy==1.9.0
pygame==1.9.2pre
pyserial==2.7
python-dateutil==2.4.0
six==1.9.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

PyCharmで試しに使用したところ (画像を提示するだけのプログラムを実行)、下記エラーが出ました。

```
ImportError: '関数名' can not be initialized. 
The Python package 'Python Imaging Library (PIL)' is not installed. 
Exception AttributeError: "'関数名' object has no attribute 'compression_filename'" 
in <bound method 関数名.__del_ of <関数名 object at 0x2b55b0>> ignored
```

この時、pillowをimportしていなかったので (他に実験制御系ライブラリを使用しており、そのライブラリをインストールしたあとは、pillowをインストールすれば自動的に使える、と開発者から言われたためです。このライブラリ自体は、pillowを使うようなプログラム以外は問題なく使えます)、プログラムに

```
import pillow
```

とし、再度実行したところ、

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pillow
```

が出て、使えずにおります。

ライブラリのインストール方法やパス設定など、私の勉強不足かもしれませんが、よろしくお願いします。

---

### 2015/2/12 追記 実行したプログラムのエラー詳細です

```
import expyriment
import PIL

exp = expyriment.design.Experiment(name="test")

expyriment.control.initialize(exp)

mask = expyriment.stimuli.extras.VisualMask(size=(100, 100))
mask.preload()

expyriment.control.start(exp)

mask.present()
exp.clock.wait(2000)

expyriment.control.end()
```

上記プログラムを実行すると、下記エラーが生じます。

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/ユーザ名/PycharmProjects/first_test/test0.py
Expyriment 0.7.0 (Revision 7a6b73d; Python 2.7.6) 
File: test0.py (91a9a8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ユーザ名/PycharmProjects/first_test/test0.py", line 9, in <module>
    mask = expyriment.stimuli.extras.VisualMask(size=(100, 100))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/expyriment/stimuli/extras/_visualmask.py", line 61, in __init__
    raise ImportError(message)
ImportError: VisualMask can not be initialized.
The Python package 'Python Imaging Library (PIL)' is not installed.
Exception AttributeError: "'VisualMask' object has no attribute '_compression_filename'" in <bound method VisualMask.__del__ of <expyriment.stimuli.extras._visualmask.VisualMask object at 0x2b55b0>> ignored

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `import pillow` ではなく、`from PIL import Image` などとするのではないでしょうか。

Comment: こちら（http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5067/python-pillow-pil-%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92-mavericks-10-9-5-%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84/5081?noredirect=1#comment3898_5081）のコメントの内容も本文に含めた方がいいと思います。あと、numpyとpipのインストール方法も書いた方がいいです。

Comment: @heliac2001 下記のようなエラーが出ます。
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/PIL/Image.py", line 62, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.3-fat/egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/ユーザ名/.python-eggs/Pillow-2.6.1-py2.7-macosx-10.3-fat.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart
  ...
  Expected in: dynamic lookup`

Comment: @Rikka こちら [osx - dyld: Symbol not found: _jpeg_resync_to_restart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252852/dyld-symbol-not-found-jpeg-resync-to-restart) が参考になるかと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おそらくpipとnumpyはhomebrewでインストールしていて、pipでインストールしたライブラリのパスがPYTHONPATHに含まれていない、という状態になっていると予想しています。その前提で回答させていただきます。

まず、pipで適当に何かインストールし、どのディレクトリにインストールされたかメモしておいて下さい。以前の質問で確認していただいた`arror`でもいいです。インストール済みの場合は一度`pip uninstall arrow`でアンインストールして、再度インストールして下さい。インストールログの中でパスが表示され、パスの中に`site-packages`というディレクトリがあるはずです。

ターミナル上で`echo $PYTHONPATH`を実行してPYTHONPATHが設定されているか確認して下さい。（おそらく何も出力されないと思いますが、）出力に上記の`site-packages`を含むパスは含まれているでしょうか？

また、pythonのインタープリタまたはスクリプトで以下を実行し、出力の中に先ほどのパスが含まれているか確認して下さい。

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

両方にパスが含まれていない場合、PATHの設定が必要です。`~/.bash_profile`か`~/.profile`を開き（なければ作ってください）、先ほどのパス（`site-pachages`へのパス）を設定してください。

```
# ついでにシステムのPythonのライブラリも追加。しなくても良いはず
export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
# 例: export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=/(pipでのインストール先のパス)/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
# または、homebrew使用なら次の書き方でもいいはずです
export PYTHONPATH=`brew --prefix`/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

以上の設定をして、<s>新たにターミナルを立ち上げ</s>一旦ログアウトしてログインしなおし、pythonインタープリタを起動し、importを試してみて下さい。

---

#### 2015年2月11日 追記

以下のコマンドをターミナルで上から順に一行ずつ実行して下さい。二行目のパスの部分はご自分の環境に合わせて修正してください。

```
echo "export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PYTHONPATH=/(pipでのインストール先のパス)/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
echo "export PYTHONPATH=`brew --prefix`/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

その上で、一旦ログアウトしてログインし直し、再度pythonのインタープリターを立ち上げてimportを試してみてください。

Comment: ＠Miyako 確認させていただきます。`echo $PYTHONPATH`と`import sys
print(sys.path)`の両方で何も出力されませんでした。これは両方にパスが含まれていない、ということでしょうか。

Comment: おそらくそうなので、後半の設定を試してみてください

Comment: すみません、最後にログインし直す必要があります。回答の方の手順も修正しました。

Comment: ＠Miyako `~/.bash_profile`をターミナルで入力すると、`Permission denied`が返されました。私なりに調べたのですが、要領を得られませんでした。`~/.bash_profile`を開くには、何か他に入力すべきことがあるのでしょうか。初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`~/.bash_profile`というファイルが存在することがわかりました。試していただきたいことを回答本文に追記しましたので、試していただけますでしょうか。「開くには〜」に関しては本質問と全く関係ないので、必要でしたら別質問でお願いします。

Comment: ＠Miyako追記の内容を実行してみました。各入力文を入力すると　`>>`　が表示され、エラーもありませんでした。ログインし直した後、import PILを行うとエラーはでませんでした (import pillowはエラーがでます)。しかし、画像処理を行うプログラムを実行すると、質問に記載したものと同じエラーが出ます。

Comment: @Rikka その画像処理を行うプログラムディレクトリにターミナルで移動(`cd`)し、`python そのスクリプト.py`で実行してもダメですか？

Comment: 他の回答のコメントを読む限り、エラーになるようですね。そうなると、その「画像処理を行うプログラム」の問題だと思います。

Comment: @Miyako画像処理のプログラムとエラーの詳細を質問に追記しました。よければご確認ください。もし、この質問とは異なる問題でしたら、また別に質問を作成させていただきます。ここで使用している画像処理などの実験制御用ライブラリが原因でしょうか (開発者はPILがあれば動作すると連絡をくれているのですが)。

Comment: @Rikka 最初にimport している expyriment は、[これ](http://docs.expyriment.org/index.html)でしょうか？だとすると、ちょっと試すにはハードルが高いので、申し訳ありませんが私の手元の環境では試せそうにありません。`import PIL`や`from PIL import Image`が実行できるのでしたら、質問タイトルの「Python Pillow/PILライブラリをMavericks (10.9.5) で使えない」は解決しているように思えますので、他の質問を作られた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: @MiyakoPIL自体は使用可能となりました (プログラムのエラーも修正できそうです)。本当にありがとうございます。ご迷惑おかけしました。

Answer (score 1):

参考までに私の環境(OS X Mervericks)でpillowに依存するqrcodeを動作させてみましたが、
特に問題なく動作しました。インストールはターミナルから以下の様に実行しています。

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install pillow
$ sudo pip install qrcode
```

コードは長くなるので掲載できませんが、pillowがないと動作しないので動作はできていると思います。
なお、環境変数PYTHON_PATHは特に指定していません（envコマンドで確認できません）。

---

pillowがインストールされても `import pillow` はエラーとなります。`import PIL` を試してみてください。
PyCharmをお使いとのことですが、Macのターミナルから以下を実行した場合はどうでしょうか。

```
$ python
>>> import PIL
>>> exit()
```

PyCharmで確認する場合はPyCharmのToolメニューからPython Consoleを開き、

```
>>> import PIL
```

を試してみてください。
PyCharmから起動させる場合の動作を確認するにはこちらの方が良いですね。

また、PyCharmではプロジェクト設定でproject interpreterがどう設定されているかも確認してみてください。特に複数バージョンのPythonが入っている場合、どのPythonにpillowがインストールされたかも問題になります。
確認するには `PyCharm` > `Preferences` から
`project: プロジェクト名`の下にある project interpreterを選択して確認できます。

[image: project interpreter]

追記：

ターミナルから確認するのは、`import pillow`ではなく`import PIL`でした。
  `import pillow`は私のMac環境、Windows環境いずれでもエラーになります。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pillow
```

Comment: @fliedonionありがとうございます。PyCharm の Python Console から`import PIL`は正常にできます。しかし、プログラムを実行すると、質問に記載したエラーが出ます。PyCharm の Project Interpreter も確認しましたが、Python(2.7.6.) にはプログラムを実行するのに必要なライブラリ (Pillowなど) はPackageにすべて記載されていました。

Comment: @fliedonionProject Interpreter で使用しているPython (2.7.6) に入っている Package一覧には、Pillow(2.6.1),PyOpenGL(3.1.0),expyriment(0.7.0),numpy(1.9.0),pip(1.5.6),pygame(1.9.1),pyserial(2.7),stuptools(1.1.5),wsgiref(0.1.2),があります。しかし、この中で、Pillow,PyOpenGL,pyserialはimportするとエラーがでます(PILはimportできます)。何か関係があるのでしょうか。

Comment: @Rikka 今出先でエラー部分は細かく見れませんが、importに関してはそれらはパッケージ名とimportで指定する名前が異なるパッケージのようですね。pillowは元々PILからfork(派生、分岐)したプロジェクトですので`import PIL`(オリジナルのPILも入ってないようなのでこれで確認できます)、他二つは`import OpenGL` 、`import serial`で確認できると思います。

Comment: @fliedonionご指摘ありがとうございます。openglなど、全てimportできました。しかし、質問のエラーはやはり治りませんでした。