# Mac Os のターミナルで ~/.bash_profile が開けない

Tags: python, macos

Mac (OS 10.9.5 Mavericks) のターミナルで、`~/.bash_profile` を開く方法について質問させていただきます (python初心者です)。

Python (2.7.6.) のライブラリ (すでにインストール済みのもの) をimportして使用できるようにするために、パス設定をしようとしています。
([Python Pillow/PILライブラリをMavericks (10.9.5) で使えない](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5875/python-pillow-pil%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92mavericks-10-9-5-%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%88%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84))

PYTHONPATHの設定を確認するため、ターミナル上で下記を入力しました。

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

もしくは、

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
```

しかし、双方何も出力されず、パス設定がされていないことがわかりました。
そのためパス設定を行うべく、`~/.bash_profile`ターミナルに入力したのですが、`Permission denied`と出力され、開くことができませんでした。

`~/.bash_profile`を開き、パス設定をする方法をご存じでしたら、ご教示いただければ幸いです。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

入力したコマンドがわかりませんが、`~\.bash_profile` はコマンドではありませんので、
編集であれば

```
$ vim ~/.bash_profile
```

などとすることになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。開けました。

Answer (score 4):

一応、開かずに済ます方法を以前の質問に書いたのですが・・・なにかすごく申し訳ありません・・・

ホームディレクトリに.bash_profileという隠しファイルがあるはずなので、お好きなエディタで開いて編集して下さい、開けるはずです。コマンドラインから実行したいのであれば、

```
open ~/.bash_profile
```

を実行して下さい。おそらくテキストエディットが起動されて編集できるはずです。

Comment: @Miyakoこちらこそ勉強不足でした。無事解決しました。

Answer (score 3):

```
open -e ~/.bash_profile
```